# Database Update(add column) SQFlite Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

When I run the application, I would like to check if the database is in version 2, if not, add a column. If it is the first installation, version 2 will already be installed.

```
class DiariaHelpers {
//criar e conectar ao banco de dados

//definindo estrutura da tabela

  String nomeTabela = 'tbDiarias';
  String colId = 'id';
  String colTipo = 'tipo';
  String colLocal = 'local';
  String colDate = 'date';
  String colValue = 'value';
  String colObs = 'obs';
  String colDias = 'qtdDias';
  String colState = 'state';
  


//metodo singleton
  static DiariaHelpers? _databasehelper;
  static Database? _database;
  DiariaHelpers.createInstance();

  factory DiariaHelpers() {
    if (_databasehelper == null) {
      _databasehelper = DiariaHelpers.createInstance();
    }
    return _databasehelper!;
  }

  //verificando se o banco de dados foi inicializado
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await startDataBase();
    }else{
      _addColuna(_database!);
    }
    return _database!;
  }


  //"ALTER TABLE tbDiarias ADD COLUMN qtdDias Text;"

  //inicializa banco de dados(criar/inicializar)
  Future<Database> startDataBase() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String pathDb = directory.path + '/\dbdiarias.db';
    
    var database = await openDatabase(
      pathDb,
      version: 2,
      onCreate: _createTable,
      
    );
    return database;
  }



//atualizando banco de dados
  void _addColuna(Database db) async {
    await db.execute('ALTER TABLE tbDiarias ADD COLUMN qtdDias Text'); 
  }

//ADICIONAR COLUNA
  void _createTable(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('CREATE TABLE $nomeTabela ('
        '$colId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, '
        '$colTipo Text, '
        '$colLocal Text, '
        '$colDate Text, '
        '$colValue Text, '
        '$colObs Text, '
        '$colDias Text, '
        '$colState INTEGER)');
     
  }
}
```

I added a column in the _addColuna(_database!) method, if the application is installed for the first time it will work normally, but it is not updating the table, on devices that are already installed.

I tried to make this update when calling the **get database async** function but it didn't work.